# Custom pictorial border to environments

Tags: diagrams, algorithms, border

I write documents full of `algorithm` environments, and they got a bit boring to look at for me, lately. I've been thinking to try to render them with a custom border, something like the following proof of concept

[image: [1]]

(maybe with the algorithm title in the window bar! but also a title-less window would be fine),
but I don't know where to start. I looked around and found code snippets for custom borders, but I haven't found much on using pictures this way.

Any ideas?

Comment: texdoc tcolorbox

Comment: also texdoc bclogo

Comment: Awesome! tcolorbox is working very well. thanks!